# PHP - Index not found in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$attribGarden` which looks like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["property"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["typeKind"]=>
      string(9) "isolation"
      ["typeId"]=>
      int(76)
      ["valueId"]=>
      string(3) "386"
    }
    ["children"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["property"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["typeKind"]=>
          string(9) "isolation"
          ["typeId"]=>
          int(79)
          ["valueId"]=>
          string(3) "395"
        }
....
....
....
```

Also I have a function on the same page:

```
function ____storeAttribGarden($data, $parent = 0){

    foreach($data as $value){

        if($value['property']['typeKind'] == 'isolation'){
            // some action here
        }
    }
}
```

When the code executes, it's throwing this error:

> Undefined index: property in E:\xyz\proc_product.php on line 1743
>
> // line 1743 refers to the if() condition of the function

I tried `print_r(array_keys($value));` just before the `if` condition, and got the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => property
    [1] => children
)
```

The `print_r($value)` gives this:

```
Array
(
    [property] => Array
        (
            [typeKind] => isolation
            [typeId] => 76
            [valueId] => 386
        )

    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [property] => Array
                        (
                            [typeKind] => isolation
                            [typeId] => 79
                            [valueId] => 395
                        )
```

So it's clear that there is an index called 'property' in the array. But the function does not recognise it. What could be the problem? Am I doing anything wrong here?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try `var_dump`, which gives you more info, like the string length. Make sure there are no invisible characters in there.

Comment: This doesn't solve your immediate problem but I'd recommend moving to an object-oriented approach with clearly defined properties / methods.

Comment: I think you should have used this:

if($value[0]['property']['typeKind'] == 'isolation'){
    // some action here
}

Comment: @WesleyMurch He did `array_keys($value)`.

Comment: @AlphaMale From the result of `print_r(array_keys($value))`, should not be that.

Comment: @deceze: Updated the question var_dump of the array.

Comment: Are you sure every element in $data has the key `property` ?

Comment: and what if you print array like this what does it shows?

print_r($value)

Comment: @AlphaMale: I have included the print_r($value) result in the question.

Comment: from where the function getting those arguments i.e. $data , where is the calling statement.

Comment: @Phil: Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: Can you please post your complete array here. so that i can test it at my end.

Comment: The actual function goes recursive at one point and since the array was too huge, I missed to notice that the `property` index was missing at one depth. Fixed that and now things work fine. Thank you everyone, for your help! I feel guilty of wasting your time now :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first I thought that you had simply messed up your hierarchy.  However, I assume you are passing `$attribGarden` like this :

```
____storeAttribGarden($attribGarden);
```

If so, then check if you are getting three errors in a row, or just one.  If you are getting just one, then `$attribGarden`'s structure is probably not uniform.

Either that, or my original assumption was correct, and your hierarchy is still off.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but it says that index '0' is not found. By the way, the array that's in the `if` caluse is not numerically indexed.

Comment: I totally rewrote my answer.  ;)

Comment: Thanks Stephen! One of the arrays in the nest did not contain the index `property`. Since the array was too huge and the actual function was recursive, it went unnoticed. Thank you very much for the insight!

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking Stephen is right and the data structure is not uniform.  A simple way to debug would be to put the following line before your offending `if` statement:

```
if ( !isset( $value[ 'property' ][ 'typeKind' ) ) print_r( $value );
```

This will help you find the spot in your data structure where things are going haywire...

Comment: Yes Farray! My array didn't have the index at one point. Fixed that, and everything works normal! Thank you for the guidance!